# Email send through Postmark API send ok but is not received by receipt

Tags: email, curl, postmark

I use curl and Postmark API to send an email:

```
 curl "https://api.postmarkapp.com/email" \
 -X POST \
 -H "Accept: application/json" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -H "X-Postmark-Server-Token: server token" \
 -d "{From: 'sender@example.com', To: 'receiver@example.com', Subject:        'Postmark test', HtmlBody: '<html><body><strong>Hello</strong> dear   Postmark user.</body></html>'}"
```

I use my server token, custom sender and receiver. I gives me this message:

> {"To":"receiver@example.com","SubmittedAt":"2017-06-29T08:27:49.1227844-04:00","MessageID":"a3c4b03d-56db-4085-913a-47c047c14216","ErrorCode":0,"Message":"OK"}

It seems that everything is ok, but the receiver doesn't receive anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Postmark's API to look up the details of your message.

```bash
curl "https://api.postmarkapp.com/messages/outbound/a3c4b03d-56db-4085-913a-47c047c14216/details" \
  -X GET \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "X-Postmark-Server-Token: server token"
```

You will get a JSON object that looks something like this:

```json
{
   "HtmlBody":"<html><body><strong>Hello</strong> dear   Postmark user.</body></html>",
   "MessageID":"a3c4b03d-56db-4085-913a-47c047c14216",
   "MessageStream":"outbound",
   "To":[
      {
         "Email":"receiver@example.com",
         "Name":""
      }
   "Recipients":[
      "receiver@example.com"
   ],
   "ReceivedAt":"2023-09-08T13:25:48-04:00",
   "From":"<sender@example.com>",
   "Subject":"Postmark test",
   "Status":"Sent",
   "Sandboxed":false,
   "MessageEvents":[
      {
         "Recipient":"receiver@example.com",
         "Type":"Delivered",
         "ReceivedAt":"2023-09-08T13:25:48.0000000-04:00"
      }
   ]
}
```

Check that the following key/value pairs are present:

- `"Status":"Sent"`
- `"Sandboxed":false`
- `"Type":"Delivered"`:

If your values match exactly, then the problem is on the receiving domain. 
If not, hopefully, the value will give you some clue regarding the issue.